# gcloud kms decrypt without --ciphertext-file

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-kms

am able to encrypt without --ciphertext-file file path using the below command

```
echo -n mytext | gcloud kms encrypt --plaintext-file=- \
 --ciphertext-file=- --location=xxxx --keyring=xxx \
 --key=xxxx | base64
```

the above command returns a response `CiQALDSTqyFnlrxtK9phQqLb849IZTiIOvjsG2.....`

now I want to decrypt  `CiQALDSTqyFnlrxtK9phQqLb849IZTiIOvjsG2.....`.

below is what I tried but didn't work for me

```
echo -n CiQALDSTqyFnlrxtK9phQqLb849IZTiIOvjsG2..... | \
 gcloud kms decrypt --plaintext-file=- \
 --ciphertext-file=- --location=xxx --keyring=xxx \
 --key=xxx | base64
```

got the error `ERROR: (gcloud.kms.decrypt) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Decryption failed: the ciphertext is invalid.`

Thanks, any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `base64` command in your first example *encodes* the value. You have to *decode* the value in your second command:

```
echo -n CiQALDSTqyFnlrxtK9phQqLb849IZTiIOvjsG2..... | \
 base64 --decode | \
 gcloud kms decrypt --plaintext-file=- \
 --ciphertext-file=- --location=xxx --keyring=xxx \
 --key=xxx
```